# Pushing more than one item in a group using push

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to use the aggregation framework in Spring data MongoDB to build the below query in Java. The documentation around aggregation is pretty poor.

How can I turn the DSL into this query

```
{$unwind : "$item"},
{$unwind : "$item.itemSubSection"},
{$unwind : "$item.itemSubSection.itemProperties"},
{$match : {
    "item.itemSubSection.itemProperties.itemName" : {$nin: ["someItem", 
        "someOtherItem"]}}
    },
    {$match : {"item.itemSubSection.itemProperties.someProperty" : {$exists : true}}},
{$group : 
    { _id: "$_id",
      itemId: {$first : "$itemId"},
      name : {$first : "$name"},
      version : {$first : "$version"},
      itemData: {$push : {label : "$item.itemSubSection.itemProperties.data.someData", 
        userValue : "$item.itemSubSection.itemProperties.itemValue"}},
      createdDateTime : {$first : "$createdDatetime"}
    }}
```

Specifically this part

```
          itemData: {$push : {label : "$item.itemSubSection.itemProperties.data.someData", 
        value: "$item.itemSubSection.itemProperties.itemValue"}}
```

push() just seems to allow you to add 1 item? The in code documentation is basically non existent.

The output of this query in the shell for that section is:

```
"itemData" : [ 
    {
        "label" : "xxyyy",
        "value" : "123456789012"
    }, 
    {
        "label" : "tttyyyyy",
        "value" : "234DGD"
    }, 
    {
        "label" : "sdfsfsdf",
        "value" : "TR"
    }]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the BasicDBObject to any of the aggregation stage.

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            group("somegroup").
            push(new BasicDBObject   
                 ("label", "$item.itemSubSection.itemProperties.data.someData").append
                 ("value", "$item.itemSubSection.itemProperties.itemValue"))
                 .as("itemData"));
```